# Meteor app using NGINX as load balancer

Tags: meteor, nginx

I have a meteor app deployed in DigitalOcean (Ubuntu 14.04). I was able to setup nginx and deployed my app successfully using mup. However, the problem is, this app will be used by our company and almost 95% of the total population of users have the same IP. We tested the ip_hash directive but it only directs us to one of our servers.

I tried different options, but I can't seem to figure out what was wrong on our configurations. With these setup, load balancing doesn't make any sense because all users will always direct to just 1 server.

What do you think is the best nginx configuration for this?
Please see code below:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}

upstream unifyhub {
    ip_hash;
    server 111.222.333.44:3000; # server 1
    server 555.666.777.88:3000; # server 2
}

server {
     listen 80;
     #listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    server_name www.unifyhub.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/unify.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/unify.error.log;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://unifyhub;
    #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;  # http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule
    #proxy_set_header Host $host;  # pass the host header - http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_pass
    #proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; # allow websockets
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;

    add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
}
}
```

TIA!

Comment: Why this?  add_header Cache-Control no-cache;

Comment: Do you mind sharing solution as I also wanted to use nginx as a load balancer as cluster is no longer maintain by Arunoda.